# What does one do when the moderators of a site go rogue?

Tags: support, moderators, specific-site

The moderators of WebApps have taken it upon themselves to enforce a policy that all questions “need details or clarity”, even when the questions have plenty of detail and are perfectly clear, and have closed many many questions for this reason. They refuse to ever explain what details are missing or how the questions could be more clear, and also continue to close related Meta questions asking for explanations of this new policy (which they introduced without community discussion or consensus).

- [Reopen "What do the red dashed lines mean in Google Maps?"](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5090/5085)
- [What part of the question "How do I schedule a comment on Reddit?" needs details or clarity?](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4882/5085)
- [Chat discussion on "How do I get the transcript of a YouTube short?"](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/147540/discussion-on-question-by-robin-andrews-get-transcript-of-youtube-short)
- [Why was my question on how to disable "small caps" in one's text in PowerPoint 365 closed as "esoteric" by a mod?](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5088/5085)

I think some intervention from above is needed to (ahem) *clarify* the policy.

Comment: This sounds a like a WebApps problem, not a network wide issue, so I’m voting to close for “pertains to only one network site”. If you have an issue with how things are being handled on WebApps, post on the WebApps meta.

Comment: @ThomasMarkovwasonStrike The whole point is that WebApps moderators are *locking/closing their meta questions about this issue*

Comment: If you think mods are abusing their tools, that's a case for contact us, not MSE.

Comment: Now in link form: [contact us](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/contact)

Comment: Duplicate target still counts if it's more than one moderator

Comment: They are also bindingly reviewing reopen review tasks as Leave Closed without letting them go through the review process. I noticed the problem and was about to send a contact request, but decided it'd be better if someone with more experience on the site did so instead.

Comment: To be *totally, brutally honest*, I get the impression from reading the comments on some of those WebApps meta links that the regular users there are *not very good at reading what they are told* when it comes to meta discussion. `I’m voting to close this question because the premise is invalid. The question was not closed because it was "esoteric"` getting the response `which premise is invalid?` is **absurd**; **blatantly obviously** the premise in question is the one *explicitly described in the moderator's second sentence*.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel I am the one who wrote the comment that you are commenting on. I'd like to make two remarks: 1) I had written a longer comment before, but the mod removed it 2) I attempted to fix the premise with an [edit](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/posts/5088/timeline#history_4c78aa9a-7a43-43b4-941f-21fb95baf054) but the mod reverted it with no explanation.  I agree it's not a great comment, but I didn't had the energy to write another long comment since comments often get deleted on that site. My intent was to ask what the correct premise is: it'd be better if mod clearly stated it

Comment: Related: [Does Web Apps Require Research?](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5120/7584) (a meta post by a community manager about this Web Apps SE moderation issue)

Answer (score 15):

Meh, the questions are of low quality. You'll need a heck of a lot more proof to back up your claim that these moderators are "Going rogue"...

- [Reopen "What do the red dashed lines mean in Google Maps?"](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5090/5085)
  That's just a *"What does Feature X of this web app mean?"* question... It's low quality and it lacks research.
- [What part of the question "How do I schedule a comment on Reddit?" needs details or clarity?](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4882/5085)
  This closure has been explained in a [meta answer](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4885/148626). You may *disagree*, but that's hardly a mod going "rogue".
- [Chat discussion on "How do I get the transcript of a YouTube short?"](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/147540/discussion-on-question-by-robin-andrews-get-transcript-of-youtube-short)
  This question was basically vandalized into a "how to" request. The moderators stated the OP is required to provide some input, for the question to be re-opened... The OP seems to have lost interest.
- [Why was my question on how to disable "small caps" in one's text in PowerPoint 365 closed as "esoteric" by a mod?](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5088/5085)
  All I can see here is that the OP is apparently misrepresenting the closure. We can't see the deleted question. Based on broader context and personal experience I'm more likely to side with the moderators there.

None of these cases provide strong evidence of abuse...

To me, this looks more like a case of the moderators cracking down on poorly researched questions dumped on webapps, because no other SE site would have'm.

Looking at the [most recent closed questions](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/search?tab=newest&q=closed%3Ayes), I'm not seeing any closures I (personally) disagree with, in the latest 10.

Comment: My main problem is that the mods consistently (a) close questions as unclear even though they're perfectly clear (if they should be closed for another reason, then *close them for another reason*), and (b) refuse to ever explain their decisions, even though many community members are clearly unhappy.

Comment: And that's where the suggestions to contact SE come in.